# Compilation with dependencies

Tags: compiling

noob here

rpm -i expat-devel
then need to configure make make install gdal

Now my question is
If I am installing GDAL, after installing the expat rpm, do I need to do

./configure --with-expat

or would GDAL find the expat automatically, since I installed it before?

Comment: You need to tell us what you are really trying to do, perhaps with a link to the GDAL source code or tarball you are looking at. I am assuming "GDAL" wants expat. If you installed it, either ./configure --with-expat will find it, OR you will need to explicitly tell it (do ./configure --help).

Comment: Installing PostGIS GEOS GDAL stack

Comment: Then do the ./configure --with-expat and see if it finds it. It it does not, do ./configure --help and adjust the paths or tell it the expat directly (if all that fails, you probably need another expat rpm, but I think the files are in the expat-dev you installed)

Comment: I am using an old manual. 
It gives a bunch of RPMs to install first including expat. 
Then to compile GEOS, then GDAL then PostGIS 
each WITHOUT the --with switch. 
I'm trying to find out if the manual is lacking. 
My question is philosophical rather than practical. 
Would GEOS and GDAL be configured with rpm -i installed packages automatically?
Would PostGIS "find" GEOS and GDAL automatically? Since they are both compiled from scratch? 
Or I shouldn't be so philosophical and just compile everything explicitly?

Comment: Ah, I see. I would try it without the --with first, then, and let configure find them.... _in general_ unix configure will try to look in the usual places for libs and find them.